# Noun meaning to stay in one place for a long time

Tags: vocabulary

I want my sentence to indicate I don't have enough money and I move too frequently.

"Starting a business would be almost impossible without any collateral or ...

Right now I have "long term residence" but that doesn't flow nicely.

Comment: try just ***permanent residence***

Comment: stability in my housing situation.

Comment: You could use _steady home_.